# How to insert group by results into columns of another table

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have a table like:

table A:

| grade | status |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | one |
| 2 | two |
| 4 | one |
| 1 | three |
| 3 | three |
| 4 | one |

and I have another table that I would be like this :

table B:

| avg(grade) | one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 |

How should I do this? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as following in mysql : [Here is a DB-FIDDLE for mysql](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3KrFrgJTk9MooSrP5NLANq/2)

```
INSERT INTO B(avg_grade, one, two, three)
SELECT CAST(AVG(grade) AS UNSIGNED) as avg_grade,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'one' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as one,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'two' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as two,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'three' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as three
FROM A
WHERE status IN ('one', 'two', 'three');
```

The following shall work in postgresql : [Here is a DB-FIDDLE for postgresql](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3KrFrgJTk9MooSrP5NLANq/3)

```
INSERT INTO B(avg_grade, one, two, three)
SELECT CAST(AVG(grade) AS integer) as avg_grade,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'one' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as one,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'two' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as two,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'three' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as three
FROM A
WHERE status IN ('one', 'two', 'three');
```

The above queries give me expected output as :

| avg(grade) | one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 |

If you are fine with decimal values for column `avg(grade)`
You can limit those to two places as `ROUND(AVG(grade), 2) as avg_grade,`

In this case;
The query in mysql and postgresql would be same as below :

```
INSERT INTO B(avg_grade, one, two, three)
SELECT ROUND(AVG(grade), 2) as avg_grade,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'one' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as one,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'two' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as two,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'three' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as three
FROM A
WHERE status IN ('one', 'two', 'three');
```

This will return you the result as :

```
|avg(grade)|  one     |  two     | three  |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |--------|
|   4.00   |    3     |   1      |    2   |
```

Comment: but thee was problem with last line when i deleted it , it worked correctly